# POSIX character class does not work in base R regex

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching, grepl

I'm having some problems matching a pattern with a string of text in `R`.

I'm trying to get `TRUE` with `grepl` when the text is something like `"lettersornumbersorspaces y lettersornumbersorspaces".`

I'm using the following `regex`:

```
([:alnum:]|[:blank:])+[:blank:][yY][:blank:]([:alnum:]|[:blank:])+
```

When using the `regex` as follows to obtain the "address" it works at expected.

```
regex <- "([:alnum:]|[:blank:])+[:blank:][yY][:blank:]([:alnum:]|[:blank:])+"
address <- str_extract(fulltext, regex)
```

I see that address is the text that I need. Now, if I want to use `grepl` to get a `TRUE` as follows:

```
grepl("([:alnum:]|[:blank:])+[:blank:][yY][:blank:]([:alnum:]|[:blank:])+", address,ignore.case = TRUE)
```

`FALSE` is returned. How is this possible? I'm using the same `regex` to get `TRUE`. I have tried modifications to the `grepl` parameters, but non of them is related to this.

An example of text is: `"26 de Marzo y Pareyra de la Luz"`

Thanks!!

Comment: POSIX character classes must be inside bracket expressions. `[:alnum:]` -> `[[:alnum:]]`. Also, you seem to want to use a PCRE pattern with `grepl`, add `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although *stringr* ICU regex engines supports bare POSIX character classes in the pattern, in base R regex flavors (both PCRE (`perl=TRUE`) and TRE), **POSIX character classes must be inside bracket expressions**. `[:alnum:]` -> `[[:alnum:]]`.

```
x <- c("AZaz09 y AZaz09", "ĄŻaz09 y AZŁł09", "26 de Marzo y Pareyra de la Luz")
grepl("[[:alnum:][:blank:]]+[[:blank:]][yY][[:blank:]][[:alnum:][:blank:]]+", x)
## => [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
grepl("[[:alnum:][:blank:]]+[[:blank:]][yY][[:blank:]][[:alnum:][:blank:]]+", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/jfBdlg)

When you use `[:alnum:]` alone, it is a simple bracket expression that matches a single character, a `:`, `a`, `l`, `n`, `u`, `m`.

**Pattern details**:

- `[[:alnum:][:blank:]]+` - 1+ alphanumeric or horizontal whitespace symbols
- `[[:blank:]]` - 1 horizontal whitespace symbols
- `[yY]`  - either `y` or `Y`
- `[[:blank:]]` - 1 horizontal whitespace symbols
- `[[:alnum:][:blank:]]+` - 1+ alphanumeric or horizontal whitespace symbols