# Using backreferences with gsub in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of strings and I need to change those of them being followed by a certain suffix to being preceded by a certain prefix. I was using gsub and back referencing the the parenthesized subexpression in the pattern argument in the replacement.

The problem is that the function pushes the backreference  to the beginning of the output string

```
> gsub("([:alnum:]*).suff", "\\1", "string.suff")
[1] "string"
> gsub("([:alnum:]*).suff", "pre_\\1", "string.suff")
[1] "stringpre_"
```

any idea, possibly not involving a workaround via a combination of `endsWith`, `paste` and `ifelse` ?

Comment: You need double [ like this: `[[:alnum:]]`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42013383/3832970. If you use `stringr`, you would see another result.