# regex in R: Number range after letter at end of string

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have column names that are something like this:

```
colnames <- c("a81", "b82", "a181", "b182")
```

I want to extract only columns that have either 81 or 82 at the end and before those numbers (81 and 82) there should be a letter. I want to use regex in `grepl` and the expected output here is

```
TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

What I tried so far is

```
grepl("[:alpha:][81-82]$", colnames)
```

Unfortunately, the code returns `FALSE` for all entries. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[:alpha:]` needs to be changed to `[[:alpha:]]` and instead of `[81-82]`, it can be `8` followed by `[1-2]`

```
grepl("^[[:alpha:]]8[1-2]$", colnames)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Or we can specify

```
grepl("^[A-Za-z]8[1-2]$", colnames)
```

Comment: That works! [This](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html) site says we can use `[:alpha:]`. Is this wrong or are there situations when this works, too? In case you know that..

Comment: @machine if you check the `?regex`, it says the interpretation depends on the locale

Comment: If i used the single `[`, it returns FALSE for the second one

Comment: @machine you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013292/posix-character-class-does-not-work-in-base-r-regex)

Comment: Thank you for that! Also, I was not aware that we can not use `[81-82]` which is same as `[1-8]`.

Comment: @machine the range of digits is from 0-9 and it is looking for the digits instead of the numbers

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with

```
grepl("[a-z](81|82)$", colnames)
```

[a-z] means any letter and the parentheses group any of the next 2 characters: i.e. either 81 OR (|) 82.

Comment: Thank you. That works for the example in the question but for my usecase the answer from akrun is more handy because I have a wide number range