# regex, R and [:punct:] in grep --> return items from a list not containing any[:punct:]

Tags: r, regex

I have this list of strings:

```
stringg <- c("csv.asef", "ac ed", "asdf$", "asdf", "dasf]", "sadf {sadf")
```

if I want to get all strings containing special characters like so:

```
grep("[:punct:]+", stringg, value = TRUE)
--------------------------------------------
Result:
[1] "csv.asef" "ac ed"

What I should get is:
[1] "csv.asef" "asdf$" "dasf]" "sadf {sadf"
```

if I use:

```
grep("[!\\"#$%&’()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~.]+", stringg, value = TRUE)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Result is ERROR
```

I want these special characters: € ! " # $ % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [  ] ^ _ ` { | } ~. which [:punct:] doesn't have

I know if I want the strings not containing any of those characters then I would use:

```
[^ € ! " # $ % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [  ] ^ _ ` { | } ~.]
```

but how do I do it with [:punct:]:

```
[^:punct:]?
[^:punct:]{0}?

and how could i combine ^[:punct:] | ^€ ?
```

many thanks

Comment: Some of them are meta i.e. `$` signifies the end of the string

Comment: Try with `grep("[[:punct:]]+", stringg, value = TRUE)`

Comment: Yep, with one set of `[]` you're searching for `grep("[:cnptu]+", stringg, value = TRUE)` that is any character in the set of `:` or `c` or `n` ....

Comment: thanks: i used this grep("[([:punct:]|€)+]", stringg, value = TRUE) worked fine

Comment: how can I use grep("[^([:punct:]|€)]", stringg, value = TRUE) this is false, i want the strings not containing those character grep("[([:punct:]|€){0}]", stringg, value = TRUE) also not working

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013292/posix-character-class-does-not-work-in-base-r-regex, the main problem you have is that you used the POSIX character class outside of a bracket expression.

Answer (score 0):

According to `?regex`

> Most metacharacters lose their special meaning inside a character class. To include a literal ], place it first in the list.

```
grep("[[:punct:]]+", stringg, value = TRUE)
#[1] "csv.asef"   "asdf$"      "dasf]"      "sadf {sadf"
```

---

If we want the opposite, use `invert = TRUE`

```
grep("[[:punct:]€]", stringg, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
#[1] "ac ed" "asdf"
```

Comment: thanks, and what about: how can I use grep("[^([:punct:]|€)]", stringg, value = TRUE) this is false, i want the strings not containing those character grep("[([:punct:]|€){0}]", stringg, value = TRUE) also not working

Comment: @TheDev what is your expected output for those

Comment: all strings from list not containing  € ! " # $ % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~

Comment: @TheDev updated the post

Comment: "ac ed",  "asdf",

Comment: @TheDev it is updated.

Comment: thanks it worked but why does grep("[^([:punct:]|€)]", stringg, value = TRUE) not work?grep("[([:punct:]|€){0}]", stringg, value = TRUE) ----------> just for understanding purpose :D